# Text View has to Detect links automatically in iOS

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uitextview

I have a textView in which I type a url address and press a button. There is a service which detects the link and display links information like image, description etc,

My question is, do we have any option that without pressing a button can the service be automatically called.

For Example I am typing "facebook.com" now with out pressing a button can i call my web service

Comment: What are you using? UITextView or UITextField?

Comment: I am using UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UITextField then use do this to detect text change;

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This is the method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)aTextField{
    NSLog( @"text changed: %@", aTextField.text);
    //Call your web Service
}
```

For UITextView implement its delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    //text is the new part that is added to textView
    return YES;
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add the delegate.